# Not able to change hhvm user from hhvm to nginx on CentOS 7

Tags: hhvm

I am able to run HHVM with user hhvm as it is default. But when trying to change the user to nginx I get error when checking it's status.

```
$ vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/hhvm.service
```

I add the following

```
[Unit]
Description=HipHop Virtual Machine (FCGI)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hhvm -c /etc/hhvm/server.ini -c /etc/hhvm/php.ini --user nginx --mode daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

on the config file

```
$ vim /etc/hhvm/server.ini
```

this is what I have for config

```
pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid                           

hhvm.server.ip = 127.0.0.1                        
hhvm.server.port = 9000                           
;hhvm.server.file_socket = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock

hhvm.server.user = nginx                          
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi                        
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php          
hhvm.source_root = /srv/www/public_html           
hhvm.server.always_use_relative_path = false      
hhvm.server.thread_count = 32                     
hhvm.resource_limit.max_socket = 65536            

hhvm.jit = true                                   
hhvm.jit_a_size = 67108864                        
hhvm.jit_a_stubs_size = 22554432                  
hhvm.jit_global_data_size = 22554432              
hhvm.jit_profile_interp_requests = 3              

; mysql                                           
hhvm.mysql.socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock     
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = true                   

; logging                                         
hhvm.log.use_syslog = false                       
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true                      
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log           
hhvm.log.level = Warning                          
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true   
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
```

after this I run the commands

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload

$ systemctl start hhvm.service

$ systemctl status hhvm.service
```

When I check for status I get the following message

```
hhvm.service - HipHop Virtual Machine (FCGI)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/hhvm.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-04-10 23:43:00 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 2545 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hhvm -c /etc/hhvm/server.ini -c /etc/hhvm/php.ini --user nginx --mode daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2545 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 10 23:43:00 centos7.local systemd[1]: Starting HipHop Virtual Machine (FCGI)...
Apr 10 23:43:00 centos7.local systemd[1]: Started HipHop Virtual Machine (FCGI).
Apr 10 23:43:00 centos7.local systemd[1]: hhvm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 10 23:43:00 centos7.local systemd[1]: Unit hhvm.service entered failed state.
```

Also I have to create this folder manually every time I reboot

```
$ mkdir /var/run/hhvm
```

Why does it get deleted automatically?

Comment: Same problem with prebuilt package on CentOS 7. Moreover, I found hhvm actually run and access files as root.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start it in daemon mode normally?
Just execute command you see in the service file, the ExecStart one.
And for the missing hhvm folder maybe you could write a command to make the dir before starting script using ExecStartPre or you could change the location of the pid file to just /var/run folder.
@limilaw i think you can change the user in the service file but be careful as you can mess things up.